# Jquery Validate: How do I call the PHP file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery-validate

I am very new to this javascipt, jquery world and I am having great difficulty getting to grips with it.

I have got the following in my HTML

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#frmEnquiry").validate();
});  
</script>
```

It works although I do not understand, what is going on behind that statement, especially as it validates on each field entry (which is wonderful).

I have action="" in my form definition and a submit button and I have created a process.php file which further validates and sends an email, but I have no idea how I call that php file or where I put the call or what the syntax is for doing it.  I am assuming it is based on a return from validate().

Also what is the correct procedure for returning from the PHP file with either success or failure messages.

If anyone can help at a simple syntax level, I would be most grateful as I have looked at so many possible solutions, my head is just totally confused.

I apologise for probably asking a very common question, but when you are just starting, it is difficult finding an example which you fully understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are two general approaches:

1. Oldschool form processing: you set `<form action='process.php'>` so your request is submitted to that page. Browser reloads and displays the content that you have rendered in `process.php`
2. Ajax-submit: this way you leave `action` blank, block submitting with something like `<form onSubmit = 'return false'>` and then send content using one of jQuery's AJAX-methods: [get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), [post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)  or [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It looks something like that:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       if($('form').validate()){
           $('form').submit(function{
               //Personally I prefer ajax as get and post are just shorthands for this method
               $.ajax({    
                   url:'process.php',
                   dataType:'json',
                   data:{name:nameVal, value:valueVal}
                   success: function(){
                       /*server returned some data, process it as you wish*/
                   }
               });
           });
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Now that is what I was hoping for, the actual syntax of how to do it. It also makes sense to my way of thinking.  Many thanks and also for other people's helpful pointers.  A question though - am I expected to pass the form variables in the data: section like Company:"IBM", Comment:'I always wanted to work for you' or being more javascripty the form element ID and Values, not sure how to code those yet - apologies

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the principles:

- PHP is executed **server-side**
- javascript is executed **client-side**

Thus, PHP will only be executed if you are calling the server, meaningly, if you **call an URL** (http://mydomain.com/MyPHPpage.php) or if you are calling your server through an **AJAX request** (which is seemingly the same, except there is no reload client-side).

On the contrary, **javascript is called only client-side**. So the code used to `validate()` your form is called only on the client-side (except if you have a specific function behind this that would call the server). Hence, the javascript will use the parameters you gave him to **validate the form without calling the server**. This is a very good way not to overload your server with un-wanted request (empty fields, wrong e-mail addresses...).

Anyway, you can still have some **other checks on your server side** (checking in your database if the user exists...) and return another message to the user.

To answer your question, i'll ask some other ones: what are you trying to validate? do you want to check client-side or server-side? which data and for which purpose?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am validating an Enquiry Form for Required fields and a Valid Email address.  This seems to be working well using jquery-validate.  I have coded a similar routine in PHP, as I have done this before.  I now want to go to the Server and validate again with PHP and if that is successful send the email.  I will then return hopefully to my original HTML script page, which I can then interpret and either redisplay the form or give a success message.  Initially I would be just happy to send the Email.

Comment: so if your javascript is already validating your data, you probably don't have to do it in PHP. in order to call your server script, you need to put an `action` in your form tag like `<FORM action="http://somesite.com/prog/adduser" method="post">` as described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html

Comment: @mcl: have a look at J0HN's answer to improve your knowledge. First, make it work *oldschool* and then convert it to an *AJAX Call*. And eventually, if we did answer your question, you can accept it by checking the tick on the left of the answer that fits you best

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I missed this one earlier.  Yes - John did answer my question and I was wondering how to show it was answered.  First time on here, but very impressed, with speed and range of answers. Thanks everyone mcl

Comment: -1: Answering a question with a question.  You should ask questions in comments and form a complete answer before answering.

Answer (score 0):

You need an AJAX call to your PHP script. If your form data is valid you would do such a call. You can asign a success  callback to the ajax request where you can process the return data from PHP and either update data, display a error message or something else. From PHP you can return an object or an array where you detail if errors occured and of what type. More about AJAX -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

In your case it is reasonable to perform form validation via javascript by checking the value of each field.
There is no need to send data to the server and receive information about their correctness. This method complicates the validation and is not improve protection against bad data.